# Image overflowing grid cell on Chrome, correct appearance on Firefox - Grid areas and Media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid, grid-layout

I've been having an issue with Chrome and an image that gets out of the grid cell once the screen gets smaller than 500px in width. On Firefox I don't have this issue. I've tried many different things, from using a reset.css file to (many) different CSS properties.

I've created a codepen https://codepen.io/raul-podar/pen/wvGVRaz for the issue, please try and resize to see the visual bug.

html file

```
<body>
   <section id="about">
      <div class="grid">
         <div id="aboutText">
            <p>something random</p>
         </div>
         <div id="aboutImage">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLVL8qX.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
      </div>
   </section >
</body>
```

css file

```
section#about .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "text image";
    background-color: #ffeded;
}

#aboutText {
    grid-area: text;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ed7d3a;
}

#aboutImage {
    grid-area: image;
}

#aboutImage img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 68em) {
    section#about .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 33%;
        grid-template-areas: "text" "image";
    }
    #aboutImage {
        grid-area: image;
        padding: 5%;
    }
    #aboutText {
        grid-area: text;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ed7d3a;
    }
    img {
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: try changing max-width: 68em to max-width: 1088px in your media query

Comment: @cornonthecob I've tried, nothing  changed :|

Comment: ok, just a thought I had about your code, I would still reccomend keeping it there because ems can be changed by the user, which causes issues with responsiveness

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mbnyc/pen/mdPNgGr

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin that is already closer from what I'm trying to achieve. the image still gets out of the div on Chrome but it helps anyway. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the css grid-template-row property. I wasn't specifying that I want 2 rows. Firefox was understanding this from the grid template-area while Chrome not. So this can be easily fixed by puttin grid-template-row: auto auto for example

Answer (score 0):

```css
section#about .grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "text image" ;
    background-color: #ffeded; background-color: #ed7d3a;
}

#aboutText{
    grid-area:text;
    height: 400px;
   
}
#aboutImage{
    grid-area:image;

}
#aboutImage img{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1088px) {

      section#about .grid{
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
          grid-template-rows: 33%;
          grid-template-areas: "text"
                                "image" ;
      }

      #aboutImage{
        grid-area:image;
        padding: 5%;
        
    }
    #aboutText{
        grid-area:text;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ed7d3a;
    }

    img {
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display:block;
    }
 
    }
```

```html
    <section id="about">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div id="aboutText">
                        <p>something random</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="aboutImage">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLVL8qX.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section >
```

You need to give background colour in grid class not the about text. Image is not getting outside from the grid.

Comment: hey,  if you keep the same colour in the cells obviously the effect won't be visible. but even so, you can see that on chrome the image is so much higher (it gets out of the #image cell) compared to firefox (where #image stays within its own cell).